# Why is Postgres not recognizing my GRANT statement?

Tags: postgresql

Logged in as an admin user:

```
grant select on all tables in schema masterreport to readonly_user;
```

returns:

> OK

OK, great. Now logging in to the same database as `readonly_user`:

```
select * from masterreport.sometable;
```

response:

> ERROR:  permission denied for schema masterreport

WTH is wrong here?

Comment: Whoever downvoted me and voted to close as off-topic, please take note that the question was so on-topic and answerable that I got an accepted answer within 5 minutes. Just sayin', maybe a little trigger happy there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grant usage over the schema

`grant usage on schema masterreport to readonly_user`